# How do I integrate solr to a JSF application?

Tags: jsf, solr

I want to use apache solr as my search engine for a JSF application. I have installed solr successfully as a standalone application deployed to glassfish. And I know how to configure solrconfig.xml and schema.xml to use it in my application. What i don't know how to do is how to make java bean class (or any other approach) and how to recall it in my jsf page. After two days of searching the web I couldn't find a tutorial or example neither any resource. Any help or providing a live example or a tutorial is highly appreciated since I've been working on this for a whole week.

Comment: I don't know how solr works, but I have the guess that you can use a set of interfaces to establish the communication between some Java application layer and your solr layer, right? Well, define these interfaces and make your managed beans / EJBs clients of these interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following articles from Param's Blog were very helpful to me. They helped me understand the whole idea.

[Solrj Code and Usage Example](http://www.params.me/2011/09/solrj-code-and-usage-example.html)  and  [Configure Apache Solr 1.4 with MySQL](http://www.params.me/2011/03/configure-apache-solr-14-with-mysql.html)

Comment: Thanks. I could setup my search using this tutorial along with solrj wiki's tutorial provided by Jayendra.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for Solr java client [Solrj](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj) which will help you query Solr and get back the results in java objects and convert them to java beans.

You can also [Directly map them to POJOs](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj#Directly_adding_POJOs_to_Solr)

Comment: Thanks @Jayendra If I don't use maven how do I set the dependencies that are set in the tutorial. Is it enough to configure web.xml, data-config.xml and solrconfig.xml? And for following the tutorial, is this approach true?(instantiate a solr http or embedded server, I add my POJOs to the solr server, then I set a responseWriter, construct a solr query, then I get the query results).